# Plotting the logistic function of x in R for a defined range of x

Tags: r, plot, statistics, glm

I am trying to tell R that x should range from -10 to 10, and to plot the logistic function of x for this range of values; more specifically, I am trying to plot `y=logistic(x)= 1/(1+exp(-x))`.

This is in the context of stats homework that is teaching GLM in R.

This is what I did to define x:

```
x <- c(-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Then I tried this:

`glm(formula= y ~ log(x))`

and got

`object 'y' not found`

which confused me because y should just be defined based on the x-values I am specifying, right?

I'm feeling like this should be simple but just can't figure it out.

Comment: If you are only wanting to plot the logistic function over a range of x's you dont need to estimate a glm Hint: define `x=-10:10`, then you need to plot `plot(x, your_logistic_function(x))`

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- -10:10
y <- 1/(1+exp(-x))
plot(x, y, type="l")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be quite confusing in R, it goes like this, you define the function, which you have already done:

```
logistic = function(x)(1/(1+exp(-x)))
```

Then you can do:

```
curve(logistic,from=-10,to=10)
```

[image]

Or using `plot`, which calls `curve` anyway:

```
plot(logistic,from=-10,to=10)
```